# Angular - Struggel with sanitization of Image URL

Tags: angular, sanitization

I try to Sanitize a Image URL but i will not work for me...

This is my code

home.component.ts

```
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private route: ActivatedRoute, private sanitization : DomSanitizer) {
     }

     user: any;
     img: SafeStyle;



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: {user: any}) => { this.user = data.user;});
    console.log('Data: ', this.user);
    this.img = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(${this.user.profileImagePath})');
  }
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="create_post_avatar" ngIF='img'>
    <img [src]='img'>
</div>
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change sanitization method to `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`

```
this.img = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('url(${this.user.profileImagePath})');
```